# Change the combined flair text for users without 200+ rep in any account to be more accurate

Tags: feature-request, combined-flair

Currently the text showing for combined flairs of users without any account with 200+ reputation is:

> You do not have any linked accounts with 200+ rep

When the user view his/her own flair it makes total sense, but when viewed by other user better sentence would be:

> This user does not have any linked accounts with 200+ rep

Maybe in the past such flair was visible only to the owner and others got 404, not sure about that though.

Screenshot of the current image: (in case it will change)

[image]

Live example with user who doesn't appear to reach 200 any time soon:
[image]

Totally off topic but fun exercise: why the [Google Image Search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiuujuEVdwDHOY_1o0zTBTrSBI3wQ9LyOB1v3XzbVz1zj_1ksUQAFUJo4Nm7T1dZPZVJJeB1jejdXV-STLV818sLLXHwYbxUjsvKuYDAZp_1vSeaYoUKySguV6R7oFDuK9wDcJnVlQG4Mkwvag9F5oO4irnjGeR-YuetQX2sRaFG1dDiYCwTEMt2DT6ZVb8_1CjeyQxzAA_1Sltrgj5M04m1frgdyM3CsLCs40cApGh05hpOB0nDddXZM7yz_1OFm8Yeqm4w_1Kz9dv0OeDj7vew9zBdc4OIISF2pyIQvKGidexKuMklp0gUgrOOcmRgII6UymXW1uKNG-W87eiirtrtqdYeywzpZdVPyYq6LXMz2Ma1iMWp0mXohY_1_1lD-HEDDIO2U0IAZN-N95L6fMi3el1R1UmLZNL4CI24Z97b8DdohXzykxuLGbhUI5VATALL4YBkzPqABbnHasfqChDD-fnP8YeVnM0RansjwG4jexPgB2SAqmPxFeuna5X1fPfPUhHhrN-xufJ5SXaaSlqBOPb9dOyUloISqG2pmsooesAnWx5Q5Jv88w_1nazjG7XU-IUqXNdM_1MfAbBVQ5sD691OTrdzD5c1J4b05YWiYsmLIVEMadjAkJut5omkhoWVlIw3p_1BZVoAvguxnPJl42_1dX6FjAd0wJQDM-PxuCxiSBqqSu5FBjUivLWnS9J77_1Bg2Y9kJGQnx136LQiovzb50iRYJCqsar6hwBwXjoD7JeGOj9e-PBMBJHIli_1y_1AIkLqvKIr_13e1TjrTYpX6WpNrS2xhKaSxJyQXDR4Qlei58IL_1DiwkLHo1CKtJl6ougJwcM8l7kZQ4DnGLzmxr4DOM1FzEIVE8m6DzTYQ4LqW-tsxb830O78oX001IlsKvciYN9mRNeg76Qz1h8yI3E3ol1FRTRKp9KYWjIElWhpOI_1GcGunlh0ny32_1vv0T5nIkl7wvVTTfwQYpC2FjywteDmu_1jMhyKYUf2AOdrPQqbARzHEx_1bC9ARIvm37ZFyfeteBQV-lFuIwNBkPr-NZsNwimGnsdajzq0RBxjQrl51ZNR8njXa1HHRAvBw&num=10&hl=en&bih=941&biw=1400) of that image returns:

> Best guess for this image: [things women love](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&bih=941&biw=1400&q=things%20women%20love&sa=X&ei=J6t6UOafJtO00QWVy4D4AQ&ved=0CCYQvQ4)

Do women really love the Stack Exchange combined flair so much??? :D

Comment: +1 for the google search alone ;-).